# download older versions of google-chrome-stable, chrome://version 90.0.4430.93

Tags: chrome

Google Chrome   : 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Revision :
d1daa9897e1bc1d507d6be8f2346e377e5505905-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#1208}

OS :
Linux

how can i get 90.0.4430.93 version ????